# PowerBI Report shifted to the upper left

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerbi

Every now and then (I can't reproduce this error), upon opening an existing PowerBI document, the report would be shifted to the upper left, such that a good deal of the dashboard is not visible. This does not affect the *model* and *data* layers. Is there anything one can do about this?

[image: see here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/PowerBI-view-shifted-in-Remote-Desktop/idi-p/405405

In Windows system settings, one needs to select the option "Let Windows fix apps that are blurry".